# Export a single record only Headers downing not the data (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, csv, export

I am trying to export single record from DB. I have tried to write different methods but failed. Now I try this one here, it's just downloading the headers and no data.

```
public function getExport($id) {
    $student = Students::find($id);
    $filename = "students.csv";
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    fputcsv($handle, array('name', 'class', 'section'));

    foreach($student as $row) {
        fputcsv($handle, array($row['name'], $row['class'], $row['section']));
    }

    fclose($handle);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    );

    return Response::download($filename, 'Students.csv', $headers);
}
```

Here it just gives the table head not data below. How can I get all?

Comment: Did you try using [this](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/import) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** v3 *according the comments.*

```
public function getExport($id)
    {
        $student = Students::find($id);
        $filename = $student->name . ".csv";
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
        fputcsv($handle, array('name', 'class', 'section'));
        fputcsv($handle, array($student->name, $student->class, $student->section));

        fclose($handle);

        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        );

        return \Response::download($filename, $filename, $headers);
    }
```

Comment: Thannks Dear @Raunak Gupta 
Dear i am going to update my Question please fix the problem i have little issue now

Comment: @recoverymen: check now.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working 
One more favor required from you that when this file download its name should be the name of student mean like xyz. csv for xyz student and abc.csv for abc student name. Kindly do this for me

Comment: Is this returns a student name `$student->name` ?

Comment: yes it returns but problem is that how set extension .csv with that name