# Export 1 and Export Multiple as .csv (laravel 5.3)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, csv, export

I am working on export and I want to use 2 buttons one is for export only one record and other one is to export multiple records which are selected by checkboxes. I am able to get id's in export method but don't know how to extract data from database and put it in csv file.

Here is my method *(which is working for single record export)*.

```
public function getExport($id, Request $request)
{
    $student = Students::find($id);
    $name = $student->name . ".csv";
    $temp = tmpfile();
    $heading = array('Name', 'Group');

    fputcsv($temp, $heading, );

    $values = array($student->name, $student->group);

    fputcsv($temp, $values, );
    fseek($temp, 0);
    echo fread($temp, 1024);
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $name);
    fclose($temp);
    die;
}
```

**link for this method**

```
<a href="/student/getExport/{{ $stuent->id }}">Export It</a>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/student/getExport/{id}', 'StudentController@getExport');
```

Till here it was for *one record export*.

Now for multiple record export I have a JavaScript function which get the IDs which are neededs to be exported.

**Link for Multiples Record Export**

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="exportAll();"> Export Students  </a>
```

**javascript** method

```
function exportAll() {
    var students = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/student/getExport/' + students,
        data: {
            ids: students
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == 'export') {
                window.location.href = "/smtp";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Through this method I'm getting the id's of selected record in getExport method.

**Hint** This code is working for both single and multiple records delete but don't know how to use it for export as well.

```
public function destroy($id, Request $request)
{
    if (empty($request->input('ids')))
    {
        $student = Students::findOrFail($id);
        $student->delete();
    }
    else
    {
        $ids = $request->input('ids');
        $Student = Students::whereIn('id', $ids);
        $student->delete();
        session()->flash('msg', trans('Deleted successfully.'));
    }
    return 'delete';
}
```

Please help me how to achive export for multiple records in same method `getExport`.

Thanks

Comment: are you getting comma separated Ids in controller ?

Comment: how can i test it on ? 
i test it on index file in alert there i have with commas @Raunak Gupta

Comment: Use `dd($id);` in `getExport` method..

Comment: @RaunakGupta it have commas e.g "24,22,23,19,20,25,21"

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `get` methord insted of `find`, and then you have to loop it to append in your csv file.

Here is the code, which I have modified from my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40604392/5019802).

```
public function getExport($id)
{
    $data = Students::whereIn('id', explode(',', $id))
        ->get();
    $filename = "students.csv";
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    fputcsv($handle, array('name', 'class', 'section'));
    foreach ($data as $student)
    {
        fputcsv($handle, array($student->name, $student->class, $student->section));
    }
    fclose($handle);

    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
    );

    return \Response::download($filename, 'students.csv', $headers);
}
```